# Can I utilize the free time in office on personal things?

Tags: work

My name is Zeyaul and am working in a private company in USA as software engineer. My work load some time is not very heavy/loaded. So in a week sometime I feel like I have nothing to do till next assignment will be assigned to me. So in free time, I wanted to do some personal stuff in office itself like Islamic study, reading arabic language, or listening some bayan/lecture, etc. Sitting ideal is of no use so I keep doing Islam study when ever I am free.

How much is it permissible? Am I allowed to do study or I should seek permission from manager or I am not allowed at all?

Answer (score 1):

You should ask permission first from your Manager (Hey if I have free time can I do personal stuff).

I assume you are a salaried person and they pay you to work for x hours a day, which means they technically manage your time for their work. Doing other things during such time can be considered stealing.

I assume you also take prayer breaks if needed. I personally ask them for 30 minutes personal time a day which I make up after the original shift as needed, I don't even mention it is for praying.

Also personally, on my free time I try to evolve my knowledge about my work. This way the company can benefit from my learning and experience. You can leave learning about Islamic studies when you go home or on holidays/weekends. Since I wouldn't want, as a Muslim, if I owned a company, my employees learning about Islam during work when I pay them, I wouldn't them learning about new technology and things that can benefit the company.

Comment: I assume the payment is on 'assignment basis' not, 'no. of hours worked basis', but that's my guess. As you said, it's better to take permission if Zeyaul feels he's violating the law of the office.

Comment: @azam I am pretty confident that he is a salary worker (he should confirm). Assignments are giving for developers as they come in from SH, there are two type of employment in the tech word (short term contract, 1-6 months, paid by hour most of the time) or salaried.

Comment: I am full time employee and not hour based employee. If I am sick and didn't come to office for two days, in that case as well i will get paid. I am getting 401K as well. Once in Ramadan I asked to my manager that i am coming late these days so I will manage my task at home or in evening. My manager response was, don't worry for what time you are coming or going, just finish your work and that's it.

Comment: @Zeyaul That is called flex timing, most of developers get that to entice them to stay in the company, I even get to work from home a few days a week if I want to, as you said, as long as you don't slack off and get the work done.

Answer (score -2):

As your boss or HR and be honest to them as at the end of the day they are paying you. Better to be safe than sorry.